# User form with combobox - enter key behaviour

Tags: excel, vba, key, enter

I have a user form which has a combobox drop down where user can select data and then click on the button, to search for an equivalent based on the entered/selected data.

Is is possible that they can also hit the "Enter" key from the keyboard and that it will behave the same as when they click on the search button?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a KeyDown event, providing the userform is activated it would look something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles UserForm1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter) Then
            'Do Stuff
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this is VB.NET. For VBA see my answer

Answer (score 1):

you have to:

- set all your UserForm controls "TabStop" property to `False`

  this to prevent them "stealing" focus from Userform itself
- add the following `UserForm_KeyDown` event handler

  ```
  Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
      If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then CommandButton1_Click 'change "CommandButton1" to actual name of your button you want to mimic behavior of
  End Sub
  ```